# php curl through iframe won't following hyperlinks from target site

Tags: php, curl, iframe, hyperlink

Site_a index.php uses 2 iframes:

iframe_1 is for site_a which is a navigational menu (site_a.com)
iframe_2 is for site_b which is a cobranded site (site_b.com)

My goal is to pull two of my sites together in one page through two iframes, which works with the code below. In frame_2, however, the content hyperlinks act as if they belong to site_a rather than following them from site_b.

What I expected in frame_2 was to follow hyperlinks http://site_b.com/somepage.php, but what I get in frame_2 is http://site_a.com/somepage.php

```
<?php
// curl function
function get_page($url){
    $msg = "";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, -1);

    $html = curl_exec($ch);

    if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
        $msg = $html;
    } else {
        $msg = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return $msg;
}

// domain
$domain = "http://site_b.com";
$page_content = get_page("$domain/somepage.php");

// display fetched page
var_dump($page_content);

// navigate dom to iframe_2 
$xml = new DOMDocument();
@$xml->loadHTML($page_content);
$path = new DOMXPath($xml);
$forms = $path->query("//iframe[@id='iframe_2']");
$relative_uri = "";
foreach ($forms as $form) {

    // 1 result
    if (strtolower($form->getAttribute('id')) === strtolower("iframe_2"))
 {
        $relative_uri = $form->getAttribute('src');
    }
}
```

Comment: That's probably because those links are relative (from the hostname) (like: `/some/page`) instead of absolute: (like: `http://site_b.com/some/page`).

Comment: You are correct...So I guess my question would then become what is the best way to convert relative to absolute in this case? Through DOM manipulation or would I need a library?

Comment: That should be easy enough. When you fetch the content, try: `$content = str_replace('href="/', 'href="http://foo.bar/', $content);` (of course, change foo.bar to the correct hostname) ... but this means that you need to have those pages/routes in your application and that those loads the correct pages again.

Comment: Perfect, it worked great! I did have to include `'target="frame_2"` to that string to get it to keep all the links in the frame.